# How to avoid using 'scope.$parent...' in angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

We're developing a set of (ideally) flexible, component-based re-usable templates in angularjs 1.2 to develop a series of e-learning modules.
Part of the spec requires the tracking of 'completable' components. At the moment the main controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.completables = [];
    $scope.completed = [];

    $scope.addCompletable = function (object) {
        $scope.completables.push(object);
        // also set correlating completed property to 'false' for each completable added
        $scope.completed.push(false);
    }

    $scope.componentCompleted = function(id) {
        // Set complete to 'true' for matching Sscope.completed array index
        // We COULD use .indexOf on the completables array, but that doesn't work with IE8
        var tempArray = $scope.completables;
        var matchingIndex = -1;
        for (var i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++) {
            if (tempArray[i]==id) {
                matchingIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (i>-1) {
            $scope.completed[matchingIndex] = true;
        }

    }    

}]);
```

We have a eng-completable attribute that triggers the following directive:

```
app.directive('engCompletable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // add the id of this element to the completables array in the main controller
            scope.$parent.addCompletable(attrs.id);
        }
    }
});
```

So every time angular encounters an 'eng-completable' attribute on an element, it calls addCompletable on the parent scope which adds the element id to the 'completables' array and 'false' to the corresponding index of the 'completed' array.

In the eng-popup attribute directive, we have a function to check if it has been made visible:

```
app.directive('engPopup', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/popup.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.$watch(function() { return element.is(':visible') }, function() {
                    scope.$parent.componentCompleted(attrs.id);
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

Which also uses the parent scope to trigger the 'componentCompleted' function. I've been told that referring to the parent scope is bad practise, and it is also messing up our unit tests, apparently.

I'd like to know what is the alternative. How can I let my app know that a specific component has been completed? And where should this state be tracked?

I'd really like to know HOW to do this - not just be told that I'm doing it the wrong way. Please let me know what the alternative is.

But, as always, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: One alternative would be to create a Service to be responsible to track all the components and keep their states (complete/not completed). It will remove the need for $scope.parent and the service can be injected into any controller or directive you need.

Comment: @DenisonLuz That's done it! Feel free to change this comment into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Answer created. :) Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative would be to create a Service to be responsible to track all the components and keep their states (complete/not completed).

It will remove the need for *$scope.parent* and the service can be injected into any controller or directive you need.

:)

Answer (score -1):

If that `completables` list is application-wide yo could consider adding it to your `$rootScope` along with the `addCompletable` method —and any other relate methods— instead of adding it to your `mainController`'s `$scope`.

This way you could substitude your `scope.$parent.componentCompleted(attrs.id);` with `$rootScope.componentCompleted(attrs.id);` and avoid to make calls to `scope.$parent`.